# How to stop async task from overwriting data

Tags: ios, swift

I have a listener that fires whenever data is updated on the database. This updates a property either after a certain delay, or immediately. My code is like this:

```
backendClient.listenToProperty(path) { [weak self] (result: Result<Bool, Error>) in
    switch result {
    case .success(let value):
       if shouldDelay() {
           DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .seconds(10)) {
               self?.value = value
           }
       } else {
           self?.value = value
       }
    case .failure:
        self?.value = nil
    }
}
```

What I've found is that my async task will sometimes fire after the synchronous task. This leads to the wrong value being written. It shouldn't do this, the synchronous task needs to "cancel" any async tasks that are currently in progress. How can I do that?

Comment: You cannot cancel a simple dispatch queue. You need a DispatchSource.

Comment: Example here https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/70e9543f1150bb0acc6276895bfbbf9d483fd2ad/bk1ch12p499cancelableTimer/ch12p325NotificationLeaker/CancelableTimer.swift

Comment: @matt That could work. I also looked into using `DispatchWorkItem`, which is cancellable. The only problem is I'd need to keep an array of `DispatchWorkItems` and to somehow make sure that it doesn't strongly reference them.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to handle such scenario, one way is to track the last time the value was updated and if the new update request is from an older instance then ignore it:

```swift
func updateValue(_ newValue: Bool, from time: DispatchTime) {
    guard self.lastUpdateTime < time else { return }
    self.value = newValue
    self.lastUpdateTime = time
}

backendClient.listenToProperty(path) { [weak self] (result: Result<Bool, Error>) in
    let time = DispatchTime.now()
    switch result {
    case .success(let value):
       if shouldDelay() {
           DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .seconds(10)) {
               self?.updateValue(value, from: time)
           }
       } else {
           self?.updateValue(value, from: time)
       }
    case .failure:
        self?.updateValue(nil, from: time)
    }
}
```

Another approach is to use [`Operation`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/operation) and [`OperationQueue`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/operationqueue), you can create an asynchronous operation to update the value and before running a new update you can [cancel the queue](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/operationqueue/1417849-cancelalloperations).